# Mouse down event does not bubble up in Canvas control

Tags: wpf, canvas, event-handling

I have a canvas control in my WPF project:

```
<Canvas x:Name="mainCanvas" Margin="0" 
        MouseMove="mainCanvas_MouseMove"     
        MouseLeftButtonDown="mainCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
```

In this canvas control, there are some other Canvas controls as children.

The problem is that when I click on these child canvas controls, the mainCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown callback is not called. I don't bind anything to the mouse down event of these child canvases.

The mainCanvas_MouseMove callback seems to be working fine though, it is called even when I mouse over the child canvases.

I tried preview mouse down events with no luck.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Post your children canvas Xaml

Comment: It is dynamically created. Here it is: http://pastebin.com/aeUgDans

Comment: `<Canvas Background="Transparent">` to get mouse events and set `<ScrollViewer Focusable="False">` if the canvas is inside a scroll viewer

Answer (score 0):

the events aren't bubbling up because someone on the visual tree has handled them.

you should use [snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to see who handled the events

otherwise just register the children canvases to the eventHandlers

```
public override Canvas CreateCanvas()
{
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

  canvas.MouseMove +=new MouseEventHandler(mainCanvas_MouseMove);
  canvas .MouseLeftButtonDown +=new MouseButtonEventHandler(mainCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown);

 // your code here
}
```

when you destroy your children canvases don't forget to unregister the events.

Comment: I tried inspecting it via Snoop. It looks like nobody is handling the event and it is not reaching to the main canvas, either. It stops propagating after the child canvas control, I have no idea why.

Comment: @CanolGökel did you try registering the events?